# HAProxy Deny Stick Specific Paths

Tags: haproxy

So, here's the issue.
I'm trying to stick uri to table using this:

```
stick on path,word(1,/) table nodes
```

What I need to do is to deny sticking specific paths like:

```
/sounds
/libs
/css
/images
```

Because, if first the user was assigned to first node the second user and third will have to get those path to the node assigned to the first user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`stick on` supports conditions (https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/2.2/configuration.html#4-stick%20on)
I don't understand why you do it (caching maybe?), so there is a chance it may be wrong, but this should do it (not tested):

```
acl url_ignore_stick path_beg /sounds
acl url_ignore_stick path_beg /libs
acl url_ignore_stick path_beg /css
acl url_ignore_stick path_beg /images
stick on path,word(1,/) table nodes unless url_ignore_stick
```